# json data returns default price instead of store price

Tags: product, price, multistore

I'm trying to get the price in my custom module index controller like this:

```
$result['price'] = Mage::helper('core')->getStore()->currencyByStore($product->getPrice(), $store_id, true, false);
```

But it returns the base store price, not the right price. The currency is right though.

Even if I use it like this (my other store has an id of 2) it returns the base price:

```
$result['price'] = Mage::helper('core')->getStore()->currencyByStore($product->getPrice(), 2, true, false);
```

Even if I do this:

```
$product->setStoreId($store_id)->getPrice()
```

json returns the base price.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that I was not filtering by store view like this:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($store_id)->load( $product->getId() );
```

instead of this:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load( $product->getId() );
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides setting the right **$storeId** you'd better use

```
$product->getFinalPrice();
```

This way you get real price, for instance affected for catalog rules discounts...